# ASP.Net MVC: How to use a List ViewData object or other complex objects passed from a controller to a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I am trying to access a list of View Model objects that is created in the controller from the view. I know I have to be pretty close, but I'm not quite sure how to access it.

#### Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<CovidAppV5.ViewModel.COVIDvm>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    var VMlist = ViewData["VMlist"];
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(VMlist, canSort: true, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5);
}
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<h2>Report</h2>

<table class="table" id="resultTable">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone1)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrgNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UnableToTelework)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CaringForMinor)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrgNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnableToTelework)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CaringForMinor)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<div>
    @grid.GetHtml()
</div>
```

#### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string Name, string Phone1)
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Phone1);

            List<COVIDvm> VMlist = new List<COVIDvm>(); // to hold list of forms

            var covidQuery = (from form in db.Case_Log
                              where form.Name == Name
                              join eForm in db.Emergency_Leave on form.Name equals eForm.Name
                              select new {form.Name, form.Phone1, eForm.OrgNumber, eForm.UnableToTelework, eForm.CaringForMinor}).ToList();
         

            foreach (var item in covidQuery)
            {
                COVIDvm objcvm = new COVIDvm(); // ViewModel
                objcvm.Name = item.Name;
                objcvm.Phone1 = item.Phone1;
                objcvm.OrgNumber = item.OrgNumber;
                objcvm.UnableToTelework = item.UnableToTelework;
                objcvm.CaringForMinor = item.CaringForMinor;
                VMlist.Add(objcvm);
            }
            ViewData["VMlist"] = VMlist;
            return View();
        }
```

And I'm not sure you need it but if you do here is the COVIDvm:

#### COVIDvm

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CovidAppV5.ViewModel
{
    public class COVIDvm
    {
        //All from questionaires

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone1 { get; set; }
        public string Phone2 { get; set; }
        [Column("Division/District")]
        public string Division_District { get; set; }
        public string OrgNumber { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
        public System.DateTime DateOfTest { get; set; }
        public string DateOfExposure { get; set; }

        //All from Emergency Leave
        public bool UnableToTelework { get; set; }
        public bool CaringForMinor { get; set; }
        public bool SpecialCircumstance { get; set; }
        public double Annual { get; set; }
        public double PaidSick { get; set; }
        public double EmergencyPaidSick { get; set; }
        public double Unpaid { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
        public System.DateTime LeaveFrom { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
        public System.DateTime LeaveTo { get; set; }

        //All from Family Leave
        public bool QuarantineOrder { get; set; }
        public bool AdviseToSelfQuarantine { get; set; }
        public bool Symptoms { get; set; }
        public bool CaringForPerson { get; set; }
        public bool ChildCareUnavailable { get; set; }
        public bool SimilarConditions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure that in MVC if you don't specify the type for the view data object you are trying to use (which I am not doing right now) then it tries to use the string type which would obviously give me errors. So I need to define the type of object that VMlist is, but I have tried several different ideas to no avail. I think it needs to be something like `var VMlist = ViewData["VMlist"] as List<COVIDvm>;` 
or something similar but that doesn't work.

You may also notice that this will throw some errors on the veiw: `WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(VMlist, canSort: true, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5);`  and then using it later: `<div> @grid.GetHtml()</div>` because I am not sure that VMlist is an acceptable datasource even once I have the object in the view correctly. I could be wrong about this though, but that isn't the primary concern of the question. The primary concern is passing objects from the controller to the view.

What if I wanted to pass the LINQ query result `covidQuery` from the controller to the view for example? Is that possible?

Comment: See following : https://forums.asp.net/t/2142277.aspx?How+to+bind+a+list+to+webgrid+in+mvc+razor+view+

Comment: @jdweng In the answer to that on this line: ````var grid = new WebGrid(source: (List<Tuple<int, string, int>>)ViewBag.grid1, canPage: true, canSort:false, rowsPerPage: 17);```` What do I put in place of  ````List<Tuple<int, string, int>>````? Visual Studio's recommended this: ````source: (List<CovidAppV5.ViewModel.COVIDvm> ```` which technically works, but it displays the entire View Model rather than just VMlist.

Comment: Does following work : List<CovidAppV5["VMlist"].ViewModel.COVIDvm>  You are getting a DataSet and you only want one datatable in the set.

Comment: No, error on List: ````Generic type 'List<T>' requires 1 type arguments. ```` And error on CovidAppV5: ````CovidAppV5 is a namespace but is used like a variable ````. And lastly for some reason the Viewbag does not like the parenthesis anymore: ````syntax error ',' expected ````.

Comment: See following example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/july/msdn-magazine-asp-net-webgrid-get-the-most-out-of-webgrid-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @jdweng I appreciate all your help. I don't think I understand ASP enough to do this. From what I can see that doc is less helpful than the first one. I don't understand how in the first example he can do ````var grid = new WebGrid(Model, defaultSort:"Name");```` without ever defining "Model".

Comment: Did you see in the new link : public ActionResult List()
  {
    IEnumerable<Product> model =
      _productService.GetProducts();
 
    return View(model);
  }

Comment: @jdweng Yes I saw it, I just don't understand it enough to be able to use it. I do see where he defined "model" in the code that you just posed in the comment I am answering, but not "Model". There is an uppercase "Model" and lowercase "model". In the controller he defines "model" but in the view he uses "Model" as the datasource for the WebGrid.   I also don't understand how I could use this: ````IEnumerable<Product> model =
      _productService.GetProducts();```` in relation to my code. I might just need to buy a book on ASP and read up on it.

Comment: The ActionResults does an xml serialization (deserialize) to the class IEnumerable<Product>. It is automatically done as part of the Controller.

Answer (score 0):

> The primary concern is passing objects from the controller to the
> view.

You are using a dynamic approach... I would recommend using a typed approach over ViewData. View the code changes below to see if it helps.

> What if I wanted to pass the LINQ query result covidQuery from the
> controller to the view for example? Is that possible?

Yes, you can.  Make sure to pass a type compatible with IEnumerable/ICollection vs passing back a LINQ IQueryable type (the example below does this).

```
public ActionResult Index(string Name, string Phone1)
        {   
            var VMlist = new List<COVIDvm>(); // to hold list of forms

            var covidQuery = (from form in db.Case_Log
                              where form.Name == Name
                              join eForm in db.Emergency_Leave on form.Name equals eForm.Name
                              select new {form.Name, form.Phone1, eForm.OrgNumber, eForm.UnableToTelework, eForm.CaringForMinor}).ToList();
         

            foreach (var item in covidQuery)
            {
                COVIDvm objcvm = new COVIDvm(); // ViewModel
                objcvm.Name = item.Name;
                objcvm.Phone1 = item.Phone1;
                objcvm.OrgNumber = item.OrgNumber;
                objcvm.UnableToTelework = item.UnableToTelework;
                objcvm.CaringForMinor = item.CaringForMinor;
                VMlist.Add(objcvm);
            }
            
            return View(VMList);
        }
```

**EDIT** - Here's how you would send covidQuery results directly to the view (To address your 3rd comment)

```
public ActionResult Index(string Name, string Phone1)
        {   
            //var VMlist = new List<COVIDvm>(); // to hold list of forms

            var covidQuery = (from form in db.Case_Log
                              where form.Name == Name
                              join eForm in db.Emergency_Leave on form.Name equals eForm.Name
                              select new {form.Name, form.Phone1, eForm.OrgNumber, eForm.UnableToTelework, eForm.CaringForMinor}).ToList();
         
            // ommitted previous code - add whatever else needed here
    
            return View(covidQuery);
        }
```

Comment: The code you provided is actually the first approach I tried. Unfortunately, having used the code you have here, I get the error on this line in the view ````   var grid = new WebGrid(VMlist, canSort: true, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5);   ```` error messsage: ````The name VMlist does not exist in the current context`````. Also, I am using a dynamic approach and this is intended. Right now I do have a set number of parameters for VMlist, but once I get this example working in the future VMlist will not only have a variable number of attributes but the attributes themselves will be variable.

Comment: To clarify the last comment, in the future VMlist may include Name, Phone1, and OrgNumber but no more attributes. It may also have several MORE attributes than the example here. So both number of attributes and the attributes themselves will change; therefor this must be done dynamically.

Comment: Also, I'm not exactly sure I understand your answer as I had asked if I could send covidQuery to the view and access it there to which you answered yes... but then did not do that in the code example. You used VMlist and didn't do anything differently to covidQuery. I'm sorry I do not understand.

Comment: Not sure you're understanding asp.net functionality here.  ViewData is a dynamic data structure.  The methods I suggested by passing a concrete object to the view is not.  You are referring to having a dynamic data object (like JS), you can do this is you like by declaring a dynamic type using the C# dynamic keyword.  That's out of the scope of your original question which I answered above.  Also, the WebGrid is a different question as well.  I quoted your two questions from your OP and answered those as that's what was asked.  You should probably start a second SO question for the WebGrid.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my comments lol. Perhaps I did not make it clear enough. Thank you for taking the time to attempt to answer though, I appreciate it.